# How to create a simple version of std::function class

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, c++14

Suppose that I want to create a simple version ofstd::function, which has following behaviors:

```
1. function(){} -> A void constructor
2. function(_ReturnType, Args... vlist) -> To convert function pointer to a funcion object
3. _ReturnType operator() (_ArgTypes... vlist) -> To call function by fn(Args...)
```

I have already tried to write down a version, but it seems to fail during compiling...
I design it like this:

```
template <typename ReType, typename... _ArgTypes>
    class function
    {
    protected:
        ReType(*fn) = NULL;

    public:
        function() {}
        function(ReType R, _ArgTypes... vlist) { fn = R; }

        ReType operator()(_ArgTypes... vlist)
        {
            return fn(vlist...);
        }
    };
```

With compiler error:

```
In file included from main.cpp:11:
functional.h: In instantiation of 'class nuts::function<double(double)>':
main.cpp:102:27:   required from here
functional.h:16:16: error: function returning a function
         ReType operator()(_ArgTypes... vlist)
                ^~~~~~~~
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:103:19: error: no match for call to '(nuts::function<double(double)>) (double)'
  std::cout << fn(2.0) << std::endl;
                   ^
```

Comment: ReType is double(double) and ArgTypes is no arguments. So your operator() returns double(double) which is not possible

Comment: Shouldn't your member `fn` be declared `ReType (*fn)(_ArgTypes...)`? [Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/802df8f28a763d56)

Comment: What about `fn = R`? You assign the argument of return type to `fn`. That looks strange. Shouldn't the constructor get a function as argument? [Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0bf3fc2ad5d198d4)

Comment: I think you are overthinking this: Keep it simple https://godbolt.org/z/W41hqo1WK

Answer (score 0):

Based on the solution given by @mch

```
    template <typename FuncType>
    class function
    {
        FuncType *(fn) = NULL;

    public:
        function(FuncType R) : fn{R} {}

        template <typename... _ArgTypes>
        auto operator()(_ArgTypes... vlist)
        {
            return fn(vlist...);
        }
    };
```